# Chrome extension address bar events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Does it possoble to detect keyup or keypress event with google chrome extension when user type url in adress bar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is possible by using the [**chrome.input.ime API**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/input_ime) to implement a custom IME for Chrome OS.

As mentioned in the documentation

> This allows your extension to handle keystrokes, set the composition, and manage the candidate window.

With this, you can use the `KeyboardEventType` property with type `keyup` or `keydown`.